# How to generate a link that has the Name property instead of the Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, hyperlink

I generate links using this :

```
@Html.ActionLink(page, "Nouvelle", "Pages", new { Id = @item.Jeton }, null)
```

My controller :

```
public ActionResult Nouvelle(int Id)
        {
            var sliders = db.Actualite.Where(a => a.Afficher).OrderByDescending(a => a.Date_publication);
            var partenaires = db.Partenaire.Where(p => p.Afficher);
            var nouvelle = db.Actualite.Where(a => a.Jeton == Id).First();
            var model = new ModelNouvelle { Slider = sliders, Partenaire = partenaires, Nouvelle = nouvelle };

            return View(model);
        }
```

The link resulting is something like this :

```
http://something.org/Pages/Nouvelle/1
```

I would like to get a link that has the name instead of the Id like :

```
http://something.org/Pages/Nouvelle/More-like-this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not.. you just change your route attributes.. and also change your method signature for your action..

so like this:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Nouvelle(string routeValue)
    {
        var sliders = db.Actualite.Where(a => a.Afficher).OrderByDescending(a => a.Date_publication);
        var partenaires = db.Partenaire.Where(p => p.Afficher);
        var nouvelle = db.Actualite.Where(a => a.Jeton /*this needs to be changed to the property that is doing the comparison*/ == routeValue).First();
        var model = new ModelNouvelle { Slider = sliders, Partenaire = partenaires, Nouvelle = nouvelle };

        return View(model);
    }
```

**ActionLink:**

```
@Html.ActionLink(page, "Nouvelle", "Pages", new { routeValue = @item.PropertyName /*whatever property holds the value that you want in your link*/ }, null)
```

let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes exactly what i need!

Comment: @SteveMorin glad i could help! Please mark the answer as accepted so that this question shows that it has been answered

Comment: Doing so in 1min, because appearently there is a timer on that. I will use your answer even if Saket was a bit faster to answer, because your solution gives more details.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your action with string as parameter.

```
public ActionResult Nouvelle(string _name)
```

In your action link

```
@Html.ActionLink(page, "Nouvelle", "Pages", new { _name = "More-like-this" }, null)
```